# PHP echo include variable in <head><title>

Tags: php, html, include

I am building a small personal website. To keep things small and to avoid writing things over and over again, I have a single `header.php` file that every sub-directory `index.php` file `include`'s. So, every `index.php` file has these lines:

```
$title = someTitleVariableOrMethod;
include('/var/testsite/docroot/header.php');
```

And in my `header.php` file, I have these lines (I know I could probably improve the formatting, but first I want to get the title working).

```
<html>
<head>
 <?php
   if (isset($title)) {
    echo '<title>' . $title . '</title>';
   } else {
    echo '<title>Sampletext</title>';
   }
 ?>
  <style>
    //a bunch of irrelevant css
  </style>
</head>
<body>
//this is the end of the header file, the rest is dealt with in the index.php file
```

But for some reason, the contents of the title and all my CSS show up at the start of `<body>` (I see this when I press F12 in browser) and NOTHING at all shows up in `<head>`. I just want the title contents to be put in the title tag. How could I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble, I found the issue! I was using `passthru` to get to content for the variable, which I didn't realize prints to the screen. My mistake!

EDIT: The site says I can't accept this answer for two days, but this is accepted

Comment: You could alternatively delete the question.  The solution you've posted is not related to any code in the question and so for someone else to find your question helpful is very difficult to imagine.  It is also a common thing that if you don't post all of your code it can be impossible for others to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are accessing the pages from a web server (e.g., [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) - then access via http://localhost/site/index.php). If you try to open them directly from your file system the PHP will simply be shown as you described. Also make sure the index.php has the closing body and html tags.

Comment: I am hosting them on my webserver and accessing them through a VPN so it is not public facing yet. My index does have the closing body and html tags

Comment: What happens when you access header.php directly? It should show "Sampletext" in the title bar. If not then it indicates the server is not supporting PHP. (You can create a "test.php" and in it simply include: `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` then access it to verify if PHP is functional and its information.

Comment: Figured it out! I was just being dumb: I used `passthru` to get the content for the title variable, which also prints to the screen at the same time.